# Web-scraping from Excel List of PDGA Numbers using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I have a list of numbers (PDGA Numbers) in MS Excel.  I would like to automatically search the PDGA website (https://www.pdga.com/players/) from the list and automatically paste the player's location next to the corresponding PDGA Number.  Currently, I am able to search the number and paste the location individually, but not the entire list.

First I select an excel cell and 'Define Name' as PDGA, and another as Location.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRBw1.jpg

Then I basically followed this YouTube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZRcaaAVbg

And ultimately got this VBA code to work. (Make sure the proper VBA References are checked)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADDcv.jpg

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = Range("PDGA").Column Then
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False
            IE.navigate "https://www.pdga.com/player/" & Range("PDGA").Value
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Dim sDD As String
    sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("li")(127).outerText)
    Range("Location").Value = sDD

    End If
   End Sub
```

I think I need some For Each loop, but I'm not sure. It should look like this when completed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzdrX.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're going to want to abandon this line of web scraping in favor of xlm http. Instantiating and scraping with InternetExplorer slams the processor; xlm touches it.

Comment: @Jeeped is spot on.  The images that you link in your post are not that helpful. Do the PDGA numbers and Locations span columns instead of rows??  A screenshot of the numbers would help.  Dynamic Range Names would make the numbers easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific list of players then you loop and issue XHR requests to get the info. Here I have the PDGA# in an array which is looped:

```
playerPDGA = Array(1, 5, 23, 46, 789, 567)
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, playerPDGA(), results(), i As Long
    playerPDGA = Array(1, 5, 23, 46, 789, 567)
    ReDim results(0 To UBound(playerPDGA), 0 To 1)
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(playerPDGA) To UBound(playerPDGA)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.pdga.com/player/" & playerPDGA(i), False
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
            With html
                .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                results(i, 0) = .querySelector(".pane-content > h1").innerText
                results(i, 1) = .querySelector(".location").innerText
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1) + 1, UBound(results, 2) + 1) = results
End Sub
```

---

For any page listing players:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.pdga.com/players/", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Dim nameList As Object, cityList As Object, stateList As Object, countryList As Object, r As Long
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set nameList = .querySelectorAll(".views-field.views-field-nothing")
        Set cityList = .querySelectorAll(".views-field.views-field-City.city")
        Set stateList = .querySelectorAll(".views-field.views-field-StateProv.state")
        Set countryList = .querySelectorAll(".views-field.views-field-Country.country")

    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To nameList.Length - 1
            r = r + 1
            .Cells(r, 1) = nameList.item(i).innerText
            .Cells(r, 2) = Trim$(cityList.item(i).innerText & Chr$(32) & stateList.item(i).innerText & Chr$(32) & countryList.item(i).innerText)
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Reference:**

HTML Object library

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output in several ways. Here is one of such.

```
Sub FetchData()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, Idic As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant, N$, CT$, S$, C$, R&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.pdga.com/players/", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Html.querySelector("table.views-table tbody").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        N = post.querySelector("a[title]").innerText
        CT = post.querySelector(".city").innerText
        S = post.querySelector(".state").innerText
        C = post.querySelector(".country").innerText
        Idic(N & "|" & CT & " " & S & " " & C) = 1
    Next post

    For Each key In Idic.Keys
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Split(key, "|")(0)
        Cells(R, 2) = Split(key, "|")(1)
    Next key
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub test()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sDD As String

    IE.Visible = False

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow

        IE.navigate "https://www.pdga.com/player/" & Range("PDGA").Cells(i).Value

        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set Doc = IE.document

        sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("li")(127).outerText)
        Range("Location").Cells(i) = sDD
    Next

     Set IE = Nothing
     Set Doc = Nothing
End Sub
```